# Insert Line under different lines in excel

Tags: excel

Thinking this may be a basic one but I am afraid I don't know how to do it!

If I have a long list of different suppliers but want to add a row under each group (Sometimes they will be listed more than once. Is there a basic formula for this rather than doing each one by one.

Example

```
SUPPLIER1
SUPPLIER1
SUPPLIER1
SUPPLIER2
SUPPLIER2
SUPPLIER3
SUPPLIER4
SUPPLIER4
```

to look like

```
SUPPLIER1
SUPPLIER1
SUPPLIER1

SUPPLIER2
SUPPLIER2

SUPPLIER3

SUPPLIER4
SUPPLIER4
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Mark

Comment: *basic formula*? - No. A little VBA would go a long way here

Comment: Not really.  You are going to need to write some VBA for that.  Although I think you need to reconsider your data structure.  A more standard model is to have a Supplier column and then additional columns for any other data.  Then you can pivot and interpret much more easily.

Comment: Sorry, badly explained! The way the question posted the example. It was supposed to be with all the suppliers are in one column. ie Supplier1 in A1,A2,A3. May still not be possible but thought best to clarify. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Pretty quickly done in VBA:

```
Sub split_Series()
Dim lastRow&, i&
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
If i > 1 Then
    If Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

This is assuming your Column A has the most data, and is the one with the suppliers.  If not, just change the Y value (`cells(x,y)`) to 2 (for "B"), 3 (for "C"), etc.

Answer (score 0):

One quick way, without using VBA, is inserting subtotals in a list of data in a worksheet.

1. Select the range.
2. go to Data tab → click Subtotal.

more [info here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-subtotals-in-a-list-of-data-in-a-worksheet-af9554ff-e754-417a-a75e-dfe2328ca3b4?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)